# I do not extract the data from the pdf (dompdf) using hostinger

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

I uploaded my project to hostinger, and when generating a sales report, it does not collect the data from the db, it should be noted that when working locally it works perfectly for me, locally it does collect the data and I It shows what I need, I already checked my code and according to me, everything is fine. I need help!

```
<?php
include_once "../Pdf/Nueva carpeta/dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$pdf= new Dompdf();
ob_start();
```

```
$fechaInicio=$_POST["fechaInicio"];
$FechaFin=$_POST["fechaFin"];
$Pago=$_POST["pago"];
```

```
include("../Conexion/conexion.php");
$sql="select TB_STOCK.ID_STOCK, TB_STOCK.NOMBRE_MEDICAMENTO, 
TB_PRESENTACION.ID_PRESENTACION, TB_PRESENTACION.NOMBRE_PRESENTACION, TB_PRESENTACION.DESCRIPCION,
TB_LABORATORIO.ID_LABORATORIO, TB_LABORATORIO.NOMBRE_LABORATORIO,
TB_VENTA.ID_VENTA, TB_VENTA.NOMBRE_CLIENTE, TB_VENTA.FECHA_VENTA, TB_VENTA.CANTIDAD, TB_VENTA.TOTAL_VENTA,
TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO, TB_PAGO.NOMBRE_PAGO
from TB_VENTA
INNER JOIN TB_PAGO on (TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO=TB_VENTA.ID_PAGO)
INNER JOIN TB_STOCK on (TB_STOCK.ID_STOCK=TB_VENTA.ID_STOCK)
INNER JOIN TB_PRESENTACION on (TB_PRESENTACION.ID_PRESENTACION=TB_STOCK.ID_PRESENTACION)
INNER JOIN TB_LABORATORIO on (TB_LABORATORIO.ID_LABORATORIO=TB_STOCK.ID_LABORATORIO) where TB_VENTA.FECHA_VENTA between ('".$fechaInicio."') and ('".$FechaFin."') and TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO='".$Pago."'
ORDER BY TB_VENTA.FECHA_VENTA DESC, TB_STOCK.NOMBRE_MEDICAMENTO ASC ";

$sql3="select TB_STOCK.ID_STOCK, TB_STOCK.NOMBRE_MEDICAMENTO,
TB_PRESENTACION.ID_PRESENTACION, TB_PRESENTACION.NOMBRE_PRESENTACION, TB_PRESENTACION.DESCRIPCION,
TB_LABORATORIO.ID_LABORATORIO, TB_LABORATORIO.NOMBRE_LABORATORIO,
TB_VENTA.ID_VENTA, TB_VENTA.NOMBRE_CLIENTE, TB_VENTA.FECHA_VENTA, TB_VENTA.CANTIDAD, TB_VENTA.TOTAL_VENTA,
TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO, TB_PAGO.NOMBRE_PAGO, truncate(sum(TB_VENTA.TOTAL_VENTA),2)
from TB_VENTA
INNER JOIN TB_PAGO on (TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO=TB_VENTA.ID_PAGO)
INNER JOIN TB_STOCK on (TB_STOCK.ID_STOCK=TB_VENTA.ID_STOCK)
INNER JOIN TB_PRESENTACION on (TB_PRESENTACION.ID_PRESENTACION=TB_STOCK.ID_PRESENTACION)
INNER JOIN TB_LABORATORIO on (TB_LABORATORIO.ID_LABORATORIO=TB_STOCK.ID_LABORATORIO) where TB_VENTA.FECHA_VENTA between ('".$fechaInicio."') and ('".$FechaFin."') and TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO='".$Pago."' 
ORDER BY TB_VENTA.FECHA_VENTA DESC, TB_STOCK.NOMBRE_MEDICAMENTO ASC ";

$resultado2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql3);


/*Mostrar tipo de pago */
$sql4="select *
FROM TB_PAGO
where TB_PAGO.ID_PAGO= '".$Pago."' ";
$resultado4=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql4);

$fila4=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado4);
$idpago=$fila4["NOMBRE_PAGO"];
/*Mostrar tipo de pago */


$fila3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);
$cantidad=$fila3["truncate(sum(TB_VENTA.TOTAL_VENTA),2)"];


$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @Andrés no, it just doesn't show me the data

Comment: My suggestion for troubleshooting would be to take your query and run it directly on the database hosted on the Hostinger server via command line/phpmyadmin/workbench or whatever you are using. If your query work when run directly on the server, the issue is likely with your application's connection to the server.